# XML used in Uppaal Expert

Tags: java, data-structures, graph, netbeans, uppaal

I need guidance how can i represent  edges ,nodes ,labels ,assignments ,conditions in organized way  On Uppaal while uploading a XML file . My project is basically conversion of C to XML(xml that supported Uppaal Only).  Conversion of C to XML is completed but when i upload  My generated XML file on Uppaal for the generation of Model.  Model is not showing in organized way . I am stuck here  how can i  set my x and y coordinates of edges nodes condition in a way  so that i can get a model that is understanable and in structured form.

Comment: Edge/transition layout is controlled by the nail elements, which in turn have x and y attributes. Locations also have x and y attributes. See the Document Type Definition (DTD) for details: https://www.it.uu.se/research/group/darts/uppaal/flat-1_5.dtd . So your translation needs to compute the layout and set the corresponding attributes.

Comment: You mean to say i should used above dtd as a declaration in my xml file. This will return me a structured model, when i will insert in uppaal. M i Right?

Comment: The DTD describes the scheme that XML file follows. It describes the elements and attributes. The visual elements (like `location`) have attributes (like `x` and `y`) which control how those elements are rendered in Uppaal.

Comment: Got Your Point now using this scheme i do not need to create any algorithm to calculate my x ,y coordinates for each element.this layout compute it automatically.

Comment: Or  Can u kindly describe this solution in STEPS , like how can i utilize  this dtd file to give proper x y coordinate to each element OF XML FILE.                                                                                 As i have now xml file that contains tags of transition and locations ,labels

Comment: You have to supply the x and y coordinates yourself. There are some software (eg graphviz) to compute the layout of a graph automatically, but it's a hard problem and solutions do not look as good as handcrafted.

Comment: Thank You for  corporation I Got your Point.!